# How I can plot the first terms of Taylor series arround $x=0$ of the below given function in the form of integrand?

Tags: plotting, approximation

I have tried to plot the first term of taylor expansion of the below function but I didn't come up to the plot  . Any help , Where is the problem in my code ?
The Function is : $$I(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \exp(-t^2 \operatorname {erfi}({(\sqrt{2\pi})t))}\operatorname {erf}({(\sqrt{2\pi})t)}) dt$$

```
Clear[\[Lambda], Ze, Z, ZTaylor];
        \[Lambda] = NIntegrate[Exp[-t^2* Erf[(Sqrt[2*Pi])*t]* Erfi[(Sqrt[2*Pi])*t]],{t,-Infinity,Infinity}];
        Ze[a_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-t^2* Erf[(Sqrt[2*Pi])*t]* Erfi[(Sqrt[2*Pi])*t]],{t,-Infinity,a}];
        Z[x_] := Integrate[Exp[-t^2* Erf[(Sqrt[2*Pi])*t]* Erfi[(Sqrt[2*Pi])*t]], {t, 0, x}];
        ZTaylor[n_][x_] := Series[Z[x], {x, 0, n}];
        TaylorSeries == ZTaylor[11][x] //TraditionalForm
        Plot[Evaluate[{Normal[ZTaylor[11][x]], Ze[x]}],
        With[{x = 1}, 
         Plot[Z[x] , {x, (x-(8x^5/5)), (
          -32/405 (-45+4Pi^2)x^9)}, {x, -1, 2}, 
          PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 400, 


        ]]]
```

Comment: The integral $$I(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \exp(-t^2 \operatorname {erfi}({(\sqrt{2\pi})t))}\operatorname {erf}({(\sqrt{2\pi})t)}) dt$$ does not evaluate by Mathematica 12. You might want to work on this part first before doing everything else.

Comment: But am sure that integral converge and its value for x go to infinty is 0.994....

Comment: I am sure you are right. I mean Mathematica does not know how to integrate it. Since you are calling `Integrate`  on it as part of your logic, this step does not complete.

Comment: What I should  do ? what command I should use for evaluation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inactivate your integral and then use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series):

```
s = Series[
    Inactive[Integrate][
        Exp[-t^2 Erfi[Sqrt[2 π]t] Erf[Sqrt[2 π]t]],
        {t, -Infinity, x}
    ],
    {x, 0, 10}
];
s // TeXForm
```

> $\int _{-\infty }^0e^{-t^2 \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2 \pi } t\right) \text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{2
>    \pi } t\right)}dt+x-\frac{8 x^5}{5}+\frac{\left(1290240-114688 \pi ^2\right)
>    x^9}{362880}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$

You can numerically evaluate the inactive integral:

```
s /. i:_Inactive[__] :> N @ Activate[i] //TeXForm
```

> $0.497318+x-\frac{8 x^5}{5}+\frac{\left(1290240-114688 \pi ^2\right)
>    x^9}{362880}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$

Comment: Ok, Thanks , what about plot ?

Comment: sorry your code dosn't work at me in wolfram cloud , I don't know why ?

Comment: @CarlWoll Very interesting approach, but the series expansion for `x->Infinity` doesn't look promising...

Comment: @CarlWoll I tried `AsymptoticIntegrate[
 Exp[-t^2 Erfi[Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] t] Erf[Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] t]], {t, x, 
  Infinity}, {x, Infinity, 1}] ` but Mathematica doesn't evaluate.

Comment: @Carlwoll  yes , That present a probability density function , I want to get its asymptotic series